# How to create a horizontal rule with square zig zags?

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

can you help me with this hr-style like a zip, css only
I don't even know how to start, in course it writes i need to use 2 gradients.

[image: hr-zip]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like below

```css
.box {
  height:15px;
  background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,blue  0 5px,#0000 0 10px) top,    /* top gradient*/
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,#0000 0 5px,blue  0 10px) bottom, /* bottom  gradient*/ 
    linear-gradient(blue 0 0) center; /* a line in the middle */
  background-size:100% calc(100%/3); /* the 3 with the same size */
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Or

```css
.box {
  height:15px;
  background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,blue  0 5px,#0000 0 10px) top,   
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,#0000 0 5px,blue  0 10px) bottom;
  background-size:100% calc(2*100%/3); 
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Another simplified version:

```css
.box {
  height:15px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(90deg,blue  50%,#0000 0) top,   
    linear-gradient(90deg,#0000 50%,blue  0) bottom;
  background-size:10px calc(2*100%/3);
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Styling from [Termani Afif's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67049229/how-to-create-a-horizontal-rule-with-square-zig-zags#67049319), just with the `hr` tag.

```css
hr {
  border: none;
}

.box {
  height: 15px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, blue 0 5px, #0000 0 10px) top, /* top gradient*/
  repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, #0000 0 5px, blue 0 10px) bottom, /* bottom  gradient*/
  linear-gradient(blue 0 0) center;
  /* a line in the middle */
  background-size: 200% calc(100%/3);
  /* the 3 with the same size */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<hr class="box" />
```